# Spark on yarn no response

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

When I start Spark Shell using "spark-shell --master yarn," it only displays "To adjust logging level, use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel)." and there is no response.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elp0W.png),What's wron with?

I have checked my Hadoop configuration files "hdfs-site.xml" and "yarn-site.xml," but I couldn't find any abnormalities. Below are the contents of these two files. If you notice any issues, please point them out. Thank you.

```
#hdfs-site.xml
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/data/hadoop/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>    
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>    
        <value>/usr/local/data/hadoop/datanode</value>    
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
        <value>master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.master</name>
        <value>nn1,nn2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.master.nn1</name>
        <value>spark01:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.master.nn2</name>
        <value>spark02:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.master.nn1</name>
        <value>spark01:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.master.nn2</name>
        <value>spark02:50070</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>
      <value>qjournal://spark01:8485;spark02:8485;spark03:8485/master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/data/hadoop/journaldata</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>dfs.client.failover.proxy.provider.master</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>
        <value>
            sshfence
            shell(/bin/true)
        </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>
        <value>/root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>
        <value>30000</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name> 
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

````
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.cluster-id</name>
        <value>yarncluster</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.rm-ids</name>
        <value>rm1,rm2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm1</name>
        <value>spark01</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname.rm2</name>
        <value>spark02</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.zk-address</name>
        <value>spark01:2181,spark02:2181,spark03:2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
          <name>yarn.resourcemanager.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>
          <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.store.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.ZKRMStateStore</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>3072</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
        <value>3</value> 
    </property>
</configuration>```
````

Comment: What are you trying to get? You're writing a command to start a spark shell and you've done it.